# PHP curl_init not working in console

Tags: php, curl, console

I`m using curl in my script and it works fine in browser.
But when i try to call the script from console i get "Call to undefined function curl_init()"
What could be the problem? Should i do some extra configuring for it to work in console ?
Thank you for your help.

Comment: Does your PHP install have cURL available?

Comment: Yes and it works fine. I`m using it all day, but if i run the same script from console "php myScript.php" only then i get error that curl is not defined.

Comment: Try `php -v` from the console and see if its the same version as the one on the web server.  It may be the CLI wasn't built along with the version used in web server, or the correct CLI binary to use is in a different path and the one in your shell path is not the one you want to be using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CLI and browser each have their own configuration files (php.ini). Check your .ini file that CLI uses and make sure its part of it

Comment: Yes thank you. I just came across this solution.
http://shikii.net/blog/the-undefined-curl-function-in-console-wampserver/
It uses different ini file

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you're calling the right binary? Try php -v to check the version, perhaps your php binary is from an older compile and you have a php-cli or php-cgi binary or some such that  is newer.